# How can I embed my web application

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, embed

I am a Javascript, HTML5 and CSS web application developer, but I don't know how to make my web apps embeddable, so people can embed them in their sites too. Please, any method except PHP will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please define *embed*. What interactions do you need between your application and the host site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide a javascript file that people will include in their web pages + some div with marker like

```
<div id="divtofillwithyourcontent"></div>
```

And script should fill this element with your content.

Or use iFrame if you need access to your cookies (i suggest you not use it in all other cases)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. :)

Comment: Hello, have you an example to how to do that? I have the same requeriment but in angular app.

Answer (score 0):

They could use an iFrame, or they can make an AJAX GET call, for example with jQuery. The response of the AJAX call will be your HTML5/JS which can then be put into a container(div) for the caller.

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
     alert('App Loadded');
});
```