# how to convert angular project into an api?... as well as google maps works

Tags: html, angular, iframe, nested

HelloWorld!

Actually the angular project works in a `iframe` to embebed a angular project in html pages, **and works well!** like this:

```
<iframe
    id="Example"
    title="Example"
    width="400"
    height="400"
    src="http://localhost/example">
</iframe>
```

But my boss ask me to we can get more far. He takes the idea from youtube api, for a better and correct integration
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

As you can see: youtube api do this:

1. loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously
2. calls functions when the video player is ready, and this code have other code that invoque an api with the method onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() declared previously

We want something similar to youtube api.

1- load the first min.js code async.

2- get the resources to make something like this:

```
<script>
    // ... more code
    var example = new Example();
    example.initProject(); // and remplaze an div tag with angular project
    // ... more code
</script>
```

the html will must look something like this:

```
<body>
    // more elements html

    <div id="angular-app"></div>

    // more elements html

    <script src="http://localhost/some-code.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

the `some-code.min.js` is code like this youtube get:
https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api

So, then we need to do something like this:

```
var appAngular = new AngularExample();
```

I try to find examples for this in angular to try to do my task.
Are they have some examples to help me o give some documentation to do this?

I think that there exist some npm library that makes this for you.. I not shure

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. I am having difficulty understanding your question could you please give it more focus.

Comment: Than you @Kieran I put more details in post.... hope it be helpful

Comment: @Kieran look this question and the best answere. Is that I looking for. Only need an example with angular, but I dont know how to search it https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299446/9420442